# DocuSign embedded send logs out user

Tags: docusignapi

I have stored an API access token for one DocuSign user. Meanwhile I have logged in as another DocuSign user in another window of my browser. Then I start an embedded sending flow, using the stored access code.

In the background, the DocuSign `/home` window reloads, now logged in as the user associated with the access token.

This behavior is unexpected and strange. Can we avoid logging users out automatically, with no warning?

Answer (score 1):

An Embedded Signing session is an authenticated session too. If you load the embedded signing session in the same browser, it overwrites the cookie and terminates the previous active session.

To prevent this, either load the embedded signing session in a different browser, or a private window.